# Recovery of Linux swap partition using Testdisk

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery

I accidentally deleted the EFI System partition on my HDD. I have installed TestDisk and believe I know what needs to be done to restore the HDD. However there is one issue that I can't resolve and that is the size of the Linux swap partition.
The size shown on the analyse screen is what it was before I deleted the EFI partition. This is a an extract from the log file showing the start sector, end sector and num of sectors:-

> Current partition structure:
>
> 2 P Unknown                  1050624 1937393663 1936343040
>
> 3 P Linux Swap            1937393664 1953523711   16130048

The size shown on the Quick Search screen is smaller although by only 16 sectors. This is an extract showing the different size:-

> Results
> P MS Data                     2048    1050623    1048576 [NO NAME]
> FAT32, blocksize=4096, 536 MB / 512 MiB
>
> P MS Data                  1050624 1937393663 1936343040
> ext4 blocksize=4096 Large_file Sparse_SB Recover, 991 GB / 923 GiB
>
> P Linux Swap            1937393664 1953523695   16130032
> SWAP2 version 1, pagesize=4096, 8258 MB / 7875 MiB

It probably is not a problem but before I write the changes via testdisk I just want to be sure that it won't cause any problems with the smooth running of Ubuntu on my PC.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have found advice elsewhere. Left the size at the smaller suggestion and did the Testdisk 'write'. All working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found advice elsewhere. Left the size at the smaller suggestion and did the Testdisk 'write'. All working fine.